# XPages error when running in web browser and saving new document

Tags: xpages

So I've finally move my application from development(inaccessible through internet) server to production(accessible through internet) server and I got the following runtime error whenever I'm trying to save a document:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=23, col=10: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesXspDocument.save() not allowed to access or modify file: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\notesC053A6\xsppers\22\DHRRDLYBXJ
not allowed to access or modify file: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\notesC053A6\xsppers\22\DHRRDLYBXJ

I've done some testing to see where this would occur and found that it only happen when running the application in a web browser (including the Notes 9 web browser) and creating a new document and saving it.

If I run the application via XPiNC, create a new document and save, I'm able to save the document. And this document can later be edited and saved whether in XPiNC or web browser.

I'm not aware of this problem because during development I usually only test in notes client. When it come to web browser, I'll just create a local copy to test because the development server does not allow access through web browser.

Is there any server setting that I should change? I'm not admin but I could inform my boss to change. Thanks.

### EDIT

After further testing, I found that uploading a file could be causing the problem. My XPage has fileUpload control for user to upload attachment with the document. But since it worked on XPiNC I need to know why it doesn't work in web browser and the solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the user running the service of the domino server has full access rights to the c:\windows\temp folder

If your server is running Windows 2008 and no specific user is added to run the service.
Make sure that both system and Services has full access to that folder.